# If a commutator subgroup is the identity, then G is solvable.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a group. Put $D_0=G$ and, for $i\geq 1$, put $D_i=[D_{i-1}, D_{i-1}]$ (the commutator subgroup). Show that if there exists $r\geq 0$ such that $D_r={1}$ then $G$ is solvable.

I know that given such a $D_r$ I need to construct a finite series of subgroups each normal in the next. I assume this will look like 
$$D_0 \unlhd D_1 \unlhd \dots \unlhd D_r \unlhd G $$

And I know that each quotient $D_{i+1}/D_i$ will be abelian, but how will I know that each of the subgroups is normal in the next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to show $[G,G]$ is always normal in $G$. This subgroup is generated by commutators, so it suffices you show that conjugating a commutator gives a product of commutators. Now,

$$caba^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1} = (caba^{-1}   c^{-1}b^{-1})(bcb^{-1}c^{-1})$$

is a product of commutators, that is

$$c[a,b]c^{-1} = [ca,b][b,c]$$

Alternatively, note that

$$caba^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}= (cac^{-1})(cbc^{-1})(ca^{-1}c^{-1})(cb^{-1}c^{-1})$$

that is, $$c[a,b]c^{-1} = [cac^{-1},cbc^{-1}]$$

and more generally, as noted in the comments,

$$\phi[a,b] = [\phi(a),\phi(b)]$$
for any morphism of groups $\phi$. This states the commutator subgroup is more than normal, it is completely characteristic, that is, stable under any group endomorphism.

Comment: In fact $\phi([a,b])=[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ for any homomorphism $\phi$, including inner automorphisms (conjugation).

Comment: @arctictern Yes, I did realize I wasn't being too clever here. Commutator subgroups are completely characteristic. I was trying to naïve, to see one can get somewhere.